# Firebase authentication: listen for failures

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I've been trying to listen fail events for user authentication. For testing purpose I closed my internet connection and try to sign up. Neither `onFailureListener` or `!task.isSuccessful` invokes. So how do you guys listen for failed events?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase doesn't response listener when no internet, for check internet connection you can do it programmatically

```
if(isNetworkAvailable()){
    //
    // Authentication with Firebase
    // 
}else{
    //Display message/aleart "No internet connection" to user
}
```

To check `isNetworkAvailable()`, please see [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560788/how-to-check-internet-access-on-android-inetaddress-never-times-out)